# repeating ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listactivity

Hey guys I am a working on displaying a list of items on `listview`, the code I am using is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_list_view);
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
        rtrnList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getmyLocation();
        listclass = new listClass(offersobj);
        listclass.populate();
        rtrnList = listclass.getListArray();
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this,
                rtrnList,
                R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"Name","Msg","time"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2, R.id.text3}
                );

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

problem is say I am displaying three names Avinash, Arun, Rajesh. When application starts these three names are displayed on list. When I close and again start the application the values are repeating Avinash, Arun, Rajesh,Avinash, Arun, Rajesh. I am not able to figure out how to solve this.

Comment: Each time when you open the list view make your array list rtrnList empty and load again.

Answer (score 1):

The code you show seems fine. My guess is that `listclass.populate()` modifies `offersobj` and that `offersobj` is reused over several creations of your activity. So, whenever the activity is created, additional data is populated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jonas. Some effort on debugging solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ListViewA extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // create the grid item mapping
        String[] from = new String[] {"rowid", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3"};
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item1, R.id.item2, R.id.item3, R.id.item4 };

        // prepare the list of all records
        List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("rowid", "" + i);
            map.put("col_1", "col_1_item_" + i);
            map.put("col_2", "col_2_item_" + i);
            map.put("col_3", "col_3_item_" + i);
            fillMaps.add(map);
        }

        // fill in the grid_item layout
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.grid_item, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

for more example [see this link](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)
[this also](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)
[listview about adapter, for create a hashmap, why bitmap type imported cannot show image in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6708759/listview-about-adapter-for-create-a-hashmap-why-bitmap-type-imported-cannot-sho)
[What adapter shall I use to use HashMap in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234576/what-adapter-shall-i-use-to-use-hashmap-in-a-listview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Pragna. Some effort on debugging fixed the issue.